# Nested CmakeLists.txt seems to forget qt4 package

Tags: cmake, qt4

I've got a new project to work on and it's being built by cmake. I'm sort of familiar with the system but not really a user that knows what's really going on. The project works with qt4 and in a subdirectory of the root it uses the command "qt4_wrap_cpp(...)". The problem is that cmake throws an error : Unknown Cmake command "qt4_wrap_cpp". The CMakeLists.txt in the top-level folder has the line "find_package(qt4)" in it and all i've seen this far suggested adding that line.
Does anyone have an idea what i could do next to tell cmake i've already added qt4 ?

EDIT: Structure example

root //here lies the top-level cmakelists

->find_package(qt4 required)

->add_subdirectory(sub)

sub:

->add_subdirectory(another_sub)

another_sub:

->qt4_wrap_cpp()

Comment: How do you achieve the "nesting"? Please give a more detailed example of the folder structure and CMakeLists.txt you use.

Comment: Since english is not my native language i apologize for these linguistic uncertainties. The "nesting" is achieved by having one top-level CMakeLists.txt which has at its end an "Add_subdirectory()". This leads to another CmakeLists.txt with about 6 other "add_subdirectory " lines, in one of them the mentioned qt4_wrap_cpp is used.

Comment: The command should be available in your nested subfolders, I rather suspect that the Qt package is not found correctly. Use `find_package(qt4 REQUIRED)` to make sure to get an error when the package is not found. Does `qt4_wrap_cpp` work in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: find_package(qt4 required) is in the top-level file and does not result in an error. when I copy the error producing lines into the top level file it changes nothing. Just for testing I excluded the files from the build progress and it compiles (with a warning that some other packages need stuff from the excluded ones). When I now try to make the project it won't find ` #include<QtGui>` from another packages. I'm beginning to think qt in general isn't configured right here

Comment: I think I've found a solution (although it just adds another problem): I just added the necessary commands (find qt4  etc) again in the cmakelists.txt and cmake runs without an error.